# Untrusted domain error with windows authentication in work group

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, workgroup

I have a sql instance installed on my server with windows authentication mode. 
In my client I try to connect via windows authentication connection string.  But when I test my application on client system I get following error :

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication

I tried to find the reason and I found that it happens in work groups and windows authentication.

Would you help me to solve the problem in work group with windows authentication?

Comment: There are many posts about this issue. Have you tried them?

Comment: I tried integration security = false but it didnt helped me, would u please help me with other solutions?

Comment: Please explain which answers from the existing questions you've tried

Comment: @alex jolig integration security,  adding sql user to local security policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally founded the solution that worked for me.
I loged in to both client and server system with the same username and password.